# How to Change URL without reloading and redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I would like to replace an url without page refresh and redirect with `window.history.pushState()`
I need to change:

```
domain.com/test
```

to

```
example.com
```

How to do that ?

Comment: you cannot change domain names without actually redirecting

Comment: If that was possible, I'd show you a copy of your online banking site's login form on my domain, and change the address bar to look like it was actually the bank's site ... wait, that _must_ of course not be possible, right?

Comment: oh, yes. that's right **CBroe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use history pushState or any other API to change domain names without actually redirecting. This is due to security measures.